# Executed application doesn't recognise file. Shell_exec

Tags: php, windows, apache, batch-file

I'm executing a file on my Apache server with php, I've tried a variety of methods, the windows batch file itself does execute and a result is returned.

I've simplified my batch file as follows

```
c:\code\codegen.exe "c:\47.mp3" 0 30
```

Codegen.exe is the compiled fingerprint identification tool from Echonest.

Running the batch file from within the windows GUI returns the expected result.

When executing within php over apache i get the error.

```
c:\code\codegen.exe "c:\47.mp3" 0 30 [ {"error":"could not decode", "tag":0, "metadata":{"filename":"c:\\47.mp3"}} ]
```

The error returned is consistent with codegen.exe not being able to find the file, in other words, File Not Found. In the latter part of that error message it is normal for codegen.exe to escape the slash with a slash.

The following php script i used for execution

```
<?php

$command = 'c:\\root\\test.bat';

$input = '1';

$descriptors = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"), // stdin
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout
);

$ps = proc_open($command, $descriptors, $pipes);

if(is_resource($ps)){
    fwrite($pipes[0], $input);
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    while(!feof($pipes[1])){
        echo fread($pipes[1], 4096);
    }
    fclose($pipes[1]);

    $output = proc_close($ps);
    echo $output;
    if($output!=0){
        trigger_error("Command returned $output", E_USER_ERROR);
    }

}else{
    trigger_error('Could not execute command', E_USER_ERROR);
}
?>
```

i also tried.
    exec($cmd." 2>&1", $out, $ret);

Again the batch file executes but codegen.exe fails to recognise the path, i also tried shell_exec with the same results.

More..

What is strange is that on my own laptop running windows 8 it works fine. i have no issues and the expected results are returned. I've got the same scripts running on an almost identical setup, only major difference being that it's running windows 7 and not windows 8.

Both apache servers run under the administrator account.  WHOAMI = nt authority\system

My feeling is that its some sort of permission problem rather than the file path. Although i have tried everything i can think of and I'm totally stumped, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed a permissions problem, I'm unsure of the exact problem itself, but a solution was found by adding a new administrator account to the computer and executing the windows service under the context of that account.

The root cause was possibly Apache being originally installed under a normal windows user account. That account has then been promoted to administrator and not all permissions have went with it. (i do vaguely remember changing the account.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy that file to `D:\somewhere\47.mp3` to check is it permissions problem.

Comment: i moved it to c:\windows\TEMP as returned by sys_get_temp_dir(), updated paths accordingly. I get the same error.

Comment: As I said, try another partition, or MyDocuments/Desktop folders.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have another partition, i did however try the docs folder, desktop folder and my music folder, all return same error.

Comment: php sees the file permissions as -rw-rw-rw-  for the mp3,  the calling application  codegen.exe has the following permissions.  -rwxrwxrwx

Comment: First I thought problems are special characters and escaping, but you said it works on other computer. But try to escape it anyway.